# Upload Files using reactiveForms and FileUpload component angular

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, primeng

I am using primeng for template.
And I am using p-fileupload component, but I need to use it in reactive form, so I want to know where to put formControlName as I don't get any input or something label to add.

I only see it with input and put a identifier on it, but i want to know if it is possible on this component.

Any suggestions?

Thanks, in advice!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First create your formGroup (reactive form)

```
this.form = new FormGroup({
  title: new FormControl(""),
  image: new FormControl(null)
});
```

`image` is your image component (upload). So then inside your html:

```
<input type="file" #filePicker (change)="onImagePicked($event)">
```

So you can hide your input and simulate a click on it. But the `onImagePicked` function is important. Then back to the code behind:

```
onImagePicked(event: Event) {
  const file = (event.target as HTMLInputElement).files[0]; // Here we use only the first file (single file)
  this.form.patchValue({ image: file});
}
```

And yes, that's all! You can use validators as well. All as normal FormControls.